# What does the maid's ration consist of?

Tags: history, food, tehilim-psalms

In  Eshet Chayil (“Woman of Valor”) that is sung on Friday nights is the phrase, "gives food to her household and a ration to her maids".

From the wording, I take it that the maid's ration differs from the food given to the household.

Exactly what is the ration given to a maid?

Comment: Sun maid raisins and minute maid orange juice. Some hold that Aunt Jemima counts as a maid too.

Comment: Again. Sorry, but you are looking in the wrong place: Proverbs is focusing on how the lady of the house takes care of a huge number of different aspects, showing the strength of her character. It's not a legal code, nor a historical cookbook. We have a little bit of Mishnaic law about feeding workers and feeding wives. Otherwise, are you asking more of a Biblical archeology question? "What was typically eaten by household staff in the Early First Temple Period?" That may be beyond our scope.

Answer (score 11):

**WHATEVER WAS ESTABLISHED AT THE TIME OF EMPLOYMENT**.

The word in Hebrew is "chok", as in *law* ... "ration" isn't the best translation. It means that her family gets whatever they want / is available, whereas the staff get a fixed amount, *what was agreed-upon* (or established by norms at the time).

(Malbim's language: להכין טרף ומזון לבני ביתה וחק קצוב לנערותיה כי בני בית יקבלו בלי קצבה, והמשרתים יקבלו חק קצבה
)

There is no one fixed "staff ration."

Comment: What might this agreed-upon portion have been, generally or a range?

Comment: Are you saying that the maids were usually indentured servants of some sort? (rather than household help)?

Comment: As for what was typical -- it's really hard to say. The Mishna in Kesubos does specify the quantity and types of foods a husband has to provide for his wife if he's away (mostly grain, beans, and olive oil); so I'd imagine it was something pretty similar. Bava Metzia talks about the obligation to feed your workers. And thus I'd assume it was paid help, not indentured servants. But the last chapter of Proverbs really isn't the place to look for details on this legal/historical matter.

Answer (score -1):

The metaphorical explanation per Tikunei Zohar, is that the maidens represent the rivers that go down to the sea, and the portion they receive is Torah that they receive from the Shekhinah. It's somewhat intricate to grasp but below is a citation and translation. The seas are symbolic of Torah wisdom.

Edit: Actually it's not figurative at all. Proverbs speaks for the Chokhmah, "Wisdom hath built her house" - namely the Torah.

תקונא אחת עשרה (זהו תקון ל"א):

מיד פתח ואמר, בארשית, ברא שית, ואינון שית ימים ברא אלקי"ם מאי אלקי"ם ימא שביעאה,

ורזא דמלה כל הנחלים הולכים אל הים, והים איננו מלא. עלאין שמעו, נונין דרחשין בימא דאורייתא, עלה אתמר שם רמש ואין מספר חיות קטנות עם גדולות, וכלהו שאגין על טרפין, ושכינתא אתמר בה ותתן טרף לביתה וחק לנערותיה, כל הנחלים דאזלין לימא הא שבע אינון, ואינון שבע נערות:

תיקוני זהר דף קמח/א

הראויות לתת לה לאימא קדישא דאיהי בת שבע, ים אוקינוס כלילא משבע ימים, ואמאי אתקריאת אוקיינוס, בגין דכל מיני מיא ונונין ורחשין דלאו אינון דילה, ויתון לאעלא בה, איהי מקיא לון, ומתמן הם שבים ללכת, כגוונא דתיבת נח דלא הוה מקבלא ממינא אחרא, אלא מאלין דמני קודשא בריך הוא, ובגין דא כל הנחלים דאינון תלמידי חכמים כלהו משתדלי באורייתא הולכים אל הים, ובעאן לאעלא לשכינתא, ואיהי לא מקבלא לון בגווה, אלא לאלין דמני קודשא בריך הוא לאעלא לגבה, דאינון שבע רועים, ולשבטין דנפקין מנייהו, ולכל דאתיין מסטרייהו ויתערבון בהון, ימא קבילת לון ויתערבון בגווה, אבל לאחרנין לא קבילת לון, ומתמן אינון שבין ללכת:

Translation:

Immediately, He opened and said, 'BRASYT - BRA SYT He created six, BRA EL-Ha'YAM – what is EL-HaYaM? It is the Seventh Sea.
The secret of the matter is (Eccl. 1:7), "All the rivers run into the sea; yet the sea is not full; [unto the place from whence the rivers come, thither they return again."]  Supernal Ones, Hear! – the Fishes that inherit the Sea of the Torah, about this it's said "There are the swarming things and without number, Chayot small and large. Now all of them cry out for prey, and the Shekhinah it's said of her "And she gives prey to her house and a portion to her maidens.' All the rivers that go down to the sea, behold they are seven, and they are seven maidens

that are fit to give to the Holy Mother who is Bat Sheva.  YAM is OKYIANUS, comprised of seven seas, and why is it called Ocean? Because all the sorts of water, fish, and creatures that are not of her, rise up in it; she vomits them out, and from there, "thither they return again." Like the Ark of Noah, who did not receive of another kind except from those that are before the Holy One, blessed be He. And because all the rivers, which are the Talmidei Chakhamim, all make an effort in the Torah, go to the sea, and they seek to raise the Shekhinah. But she does not receive them up to her, except for the ones that Holy Blessed One has appointed to go up to her, who are the Seven Shepherds, and the tribes that come out of them, and those that come from their side and mix with them – the sea receives them and they mingle into her. But others, she does not receive. So from there they "return again."